# Найти сумму двух наименьших значений

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = [12,423,54,1235,3,15,2,52];

let sortArr = (arr) => {
  let sum;
     for(let el of arr) {
       el.sort((a, b) => a - b);
       sum += el[0];
      };
  return sum;
    };
```

Подскажите где у меня ошибка! Нужно вывести сумму двух наименьших чисел.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Сортируем, калькулируем

```js
const arr = [12, 423, 54, 1235, 3, 15, 2, 52, 1];

arr.sort((a, b)=>a - b);
const outputin = arr[0] + arr[1] || 0;

console.log('outputin:', outputin);
```

Comment: Краткость — сестра таланта. Работает.)